# How do i trigger a jquery event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

i have this problem:
i have this code

```
if(ext!="rar") {
$('#myform').trigger('click');
}
```

and if the file extension of the chosen file is not rar, the file input should open the window again to choose another file, but this code does not seem to work. What should i do?

Comment: You are not triggering an Ajax event, bad title.

Comment: @epascarello sorry, i'm tired

Comment: If you have a click event registered on #myform, you can just call it with simply .click()

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#btn").click(function()
{    
    var fu = $("#fu");
    var ext = /[^.]+$/.exec(fu.val());
    if (ext!="rar")
    {
        fu.trigger("click");
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tugpM/1/

Comment: You must be doing something wrong... Don't you see it working on jsFiddle?

Comment: No, it doesn't work there either

Comment: What browser are you using. I am using Chrome and it works fine for me.

Comment: i use chrome too, but the script doesn't do what i need, if the file extension is not rar, then the choose file window should open again

Comment: That's exactly what it does for me with Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Oh, i see it now, but on my script i was triggering it on change, after i choose the file, if it isn't rar, the dialog should open again. Is that possible?

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that your form tag has the id `myform`, what you have done just triggers a click on the form (not even on the submit button of the form). Without the HTML, it is not possible to know what you are triggering the click on.

What you need to do is trigger the click on the submit button

```
$('#mysubmitbutton').click();
```

or trigger a form submit:

```
$('#myform').submit();
```

Comment: What i nees is if the filetype is not rar, the upload form should open again. I do not want to submit anything until the user has chosen a rar file

Comment: Then you must make a new question (since this one was closed) and ask that question specifically. You want to ask "How do I determine if user is uploading correct file type before submitting"